# Coming from a class diagram to a dialog window

Tags: user-interface, class, oop, dialog

I have a class diagram ("Customer") with some private and public attributes as well as some operations. Now I want to model a dialog (GUI) for editing this customer. The window represents the class Customer and some drop downs and checkboxes the attributes. The operations ("save", "refresh") are represented by buttons.

Design Question: Do I design my GUI dialog only for editing public attributes or also for editing private attributes?

(This is a pure object-oriented design question, there is no implementation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI should only interface with the class via **public methods**, not attributes, and never private members.

Generally it's a good idea to separate the GUI from the Model. The [Model-View-Controller](http://tinyurl.com/d3abok) design pattern is a common, tried and true approach.

Answer (score 1):

If we apply the 'encapsulation' concept, the UI should take care only for the public properties (better if them have accessors methods).